# Force Limit on User MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, limit

So I have an area where people can write their own query against my database, but I want to limit the returned results (much like PhpMyAdmin).

So I need to check `$_POST['query']` to see if has a limit statement, if it does, make sure it's under 30, say.  If there is no limit, I need to add it.

How would I do this?

Comment: Unless checked (and modified) by a Regex pattern, you are aware that this is **extremely** dangerous, right?

Comment: There is no other way than to parse the query and put the limit in it.. but even this is not guaranteed as you have cases where limit doesn't make sense. For example, if they did `select count(*) from table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preg_*` functions to check the query and inject your preferred limit.

**EDIT:** I totally ignored possible uses of the `LIMIT` keyword. Here's the edited version.

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM aa LIMIT 100,20';
$limit = 20; // predefined max limit

// possibilities:
// LIMIT N[,N]
// LIMIT N OFFSET N

preg_match('~(?<=\blimit\s)\s*(?<limit>\d+)\s*(,\s*\d+|\soffset\s+\d+)?\s*$~i',$query,$limitStr);
if (isset($limitStr['limit'])) {
    $maxLimit = min((int)$limitStr['limit'],$limit);
    // user might have already limited it so this is
    // just to make sure it does not exceed your max.
    $query = preg_replace('~(?<=\blimit\s)\s*\d+\s*(,\s*\d+|\soffset\s+\d+)?\s*$~i',$maxLimit.'$1',$query);
} else $query .= " LIMIT $limit";

echo $query;
```

will output `SELECT * FROM aa LIMIT 20,20`

Answer (score 4):

Ignoring risks ... I think the best is to use the query as a subquery and apply limit. So you avoid evaluating the query .

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
 SELECT * 
 FROM 'table'
 LIMIT 0 , 100
) AS query

LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: Oooh, I was thinking Regex but this is a much more elegant solution. But yeah, I think everyone who reads this question thinks it's crazy.